# OpenGl - gluShpere sits on its side how can i rotate it up right?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures, glut

This is my sphere but this is not all the code

```
GLUquadric *earth = gluNewQuadric();
gluSphere( earth, 35.0, 36, 30);
```

The above sphere has a texture of the earth but it is tilted on its side how can i change that?

more code

```
    glRotatef(earthRotation,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    gluSphere( earth, 35.0, 72, 72);

    earthRotation+= 0.3f;
    if(earthRotation > 360.0f)
    {
        earthRotation = 0.0f;
    }
```

i did it now this is answer (updated below)

```
glRotatef(earthRotation,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gluLookAt(0.00,0.00,1.0,//eye
        50.00,0.00,0.00,//centre
        0.00,0.00,1.00);//u 
        gluSphere( earth, 35.0, 72, 72);

        earthRotation+= 0.3f;
        if(earthRotation > 360.0f)
        {
            earthRotation = 0.0f;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotates can be stacked, OPENGL will do the rotations in reverse order (so the one you specify last is done first.

The following code first roates the sphere on the Z-Axis to till it up and then the earth rotation i s performed on the adjusted object.

```
glRotatef(earthRotation,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
glRotatef( 90.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
gluSphere( earth, 35.0, 72, 72); 

earthRotation+= 0.3f; 
if(earthRotation > 360.0f) 
{ 
    earthRotation = 0.0f; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks I understand it now correct answer is given (last bit of code of my question )

Answer (score 0):

If you're rendering about the X,Y,Z axeses, then calling glRotatef along the X,Y and Z axeses with the offsets you need, you can get the Earth to be appropriately tilted.

It sounds like you probably need an additional rotation about the X axis.

From the image, it looks like it needs to rotate 90 degrees about the Z axis.

glRotatef(90f, 0.0f , 0.0f, 1.0f );

Comment: this is how im rotating it

glRotatef(earthRotation,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

Comment: ah yeah i understand what ur saying but i cant seem to figure out the values i should put

Comment: you may also need to call glRotatef(correctionRotate, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

Comment: Without knowing what the image looks like now and what you want it to look like, we also have no idea what values to put in. Right know 0f <= correctionRotate <= 360.0f. You can either share the image and we can guestimage, or you can play around with the values yourself.

Comment: doesnt really work cos the earth just keeps totting in all specified axes and looks odd

Comment: i have added some more code ..s o u dont think there is another way

Comment: That is code for spinning Earth. In addition to spinning the Earth, I assume you want to offset whatever tilt you are seeing? This question is currently unanswerable, as it doesn't include any renderings (screenshots) of what you are seeing. The problems you are seeing are very dependent in the textures you are using as well (don't upload the texture, just grab a screenshot of your rendering).

Comment: [link](http://s1119.photobucket.com/albums/k633/arled/?action=view&current=earth.jpg) this is it

Comment: still doesnt work but thanks alot for trying to help me maybe i have done something wrong in my code i will have to double check